# Where are the Friend Hearts on the Kirby Star Allies site?

Tags: my-nintendo

On the My Nintendo website, there are missions to earn 100 platinum points by finding four Friend Hearts on the [Kirby Star Allies website](http://kirby.nintendo.com/star-allies/).

Where are these Friend Hearts located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one on the [Features page](http://kirby.nintendo.com/star-allies/features/) of the site:

[image: Features page of Kirby Star Allies site, with red circle showing where the white heart is located]

There is one on the [Play with Friends page](http://kirby.nintendo.com/star-allies/play/):

[image: Play with Friends page of Kirby Star Allies site, with red circle showing where the white heart is located]

There is one on the [amiibo page](http://kirby.nintendo.com/star-allies/amiibo/):

[image: Amiibo page of Kirby Star Allies site, with red circle showing where the white heart is located]

And the last one is on the [Buy Now](http://kirby.nintendo.com/star-allies/buy/):

[image: Buy Now page of Kirby Star Allies site, with red circle showing where the white heart is located]

Screen for finding all 4 hearts:

[image: finding all 4 hearts]

Comment: The locations on the mobile site were slightly different, but they were easy to find once I knew where to look.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Ah, I was doing this on the desktop site. But glad you could find them!